# Google groups won't let me delete the posts

Tags: google-groups

I tried to delete some old posts in a Google group owned by me.

I know that, if I want to delete multiple posts, I can do that by selecting multiple posts, as shown below, then going through *Actions* → *Delete*.

[image]

Or, if I want to delete a single post, I can open the post, then I can click the post options down arrow on the top right-hand corner of the message and then select *Delete post*, as indicated [here](https://support.google.com/groups/answer/1050606?hl=en). See the following figure.

[image]

However, in both the above cases, the subsequent window that appears (see below), does not allow me to select one of the options. And hence the **OK** button always remains dimmed.

[image]

I have tried to delete posts from other groups as well, again with the same disappointing scenario. Yes, all of these are owned by me.

The above scenario persists irrespective of whether the post was initiated by me or some other member.

Do you think you can point out what could be wrong here?

**UPDATE**

When the same actions are attempted from Firefox, they went successfully without the slightest problem.

Now, that is weird. Google Chrome is Google's native browser, while FF is not. Why should the two browsers produce different results?

I even checked whether any plug-in had anything to do with it. My tests revealed nothing indicative.

Comment: Have you tried deleting Chrome’s cache and cookies?

Comment: @Alex Yes, that appear to solve the problem. But how come that solved the problem? Please post a complete answer with relevant technical explanations and let me accept it.

Comment: Sorry, but I don’t have a complete answer, it was just an educated guess. It’s possible that the app was reading some (incorrect) details form the cache and/or cookies and thus was behaving abnormal.